# Create Azure Keyvault backed secret scope for Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I need to create a secret scope for Azure Databricks workspace backed by Azure keyvault. How can i get it created.

Answer (score 0):

There's an official tutorial provided by Microsoft showing how to do it, you must create the Secret on key Vault, then a Secret Scope at Databricks:

secret on key vault:

[image]

secret scope at Databricks

[image]

More Info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes